# Store time stamps to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I am creating a Django web based application for freelancers ,that they would be paid for number of hours they have worked on a project and also a weekly report is to be generated for weekly work and for that i need to work with time stamps so how do i implement it?

I want to create a button of start timer and stop timer, which records the time stamps of start timer and end timer?

I have a User model which is extended to Freelancer and person who hires Freelancer. How do i implement this?

Where do i edit the model of time stamps?

I have this model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_freelancer = models.BooleanField('Freelancer status', default=False)
    is_hirer = models.BooleanField('Hirer status', default=False)

class Freelancer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hourly_rate = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10)
    education = models.TextField(default='asia')
    professional_bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    professional_title = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    postal_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)


class Hirer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hourly_budget = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='hi')
    project_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    job_category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    professional_bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    professional_title = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    postal_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a bit broad, and I'm not really sure what it has to do with timestamps. But you might think about an "TimeWorked" model with foreign keys to both hirer and freelancer:

```
class TimeWorked(models.Model):
    hirer = models.ForeignKey('Hirer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    freelancer = models.ForeignKey('Freelancer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rate = models.IntegerField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

so you can create an instance of this class at the start of a block of time, then at the end fill in the end_time; then you can easily query the total amount of time worked for a job, and calculate the total to bill.

(Note you might want to rethink your models a bit, especially separating the project details from the hirer, otherwise each hirer can only ever create a single project.)